# Chrome://inspect#devices could not find devices for USB debugging

Tags: android, google-chrome, windows-10, usb-debugging

Chrome://inspect#devices  could not find devices for USB debugging

On Android: Turn off USB debugging, then turn it on.
After confirming "allow usb debugging" popup on android, the inspect page still says: Pending authentication: please accept debugging session on the device.

Also tried changing USB config from MTP to PTP, not helpful.
From computer file explorer, the android phone is accessible.

Chrome version is 102 on both Windows 10 and Android 8.0.

Comment: From what I recall, Android Studio's `adb` interfered with Chrome remote debugging. I would try only running one of them at a time after "allow usb debugging".

Comment: Used adb before. but Android studio is not running now. Any adb-related daemon still running? Thanks.

Comment: `adb` may still be running and you'll have to run `adb kill-server` to stop it. Just to be safe, I would plug in to other USB ports and verify that `adb devices` shows your device as connected before killing and trying Chrome remote debugging.

Comment: It works. Thanks. If you like to make it an answer, I would accept your very helpful answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android Studio's `adb` can interfere with Chrome Remote Debugging so only running one at a time is advised.

1. Confirm that your Android device is detected by `adb` with `adb devices`. This is just to avoid problems with bad USB cables or bad USB ports.
2. After shutting down Android Studio, `adb` may still be running so you'll have to run `adb kill-server` to stop it.
3. Relaunch Chrome.