# Chrome/Edge Inspect not showing android APK on Mac M1

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, chrome-remote-debugging

I was trying to run an APK on Android Studio Mac and inspect that on Edge/Chrome using the below method.

```
edge://inspect/#devices
```

But edge/Crhome doesn't show me the "Inspect" button with other details

[image]

I'm using a Mac M1 Android studio latest version. both Edge and Chrome up to date.

Comment: Possible dupe: [Chrome://inspect#devices could not find devices for USB debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72536196/295004). Disable/kill your adb-server before trying with Chrome/Edge browser.

Comment: @MorrisonChang It didn't helped me. i already followed that guide.

Comment: And just confirming that the code in the APK with the WebView has: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/ In any question always add that you've followed x instructions with link as no one knows what you've tried.

Comment: Yes @MorrisonChang WebView was enabled when building the APK. 
Sorry I should have listed out the things I tried. :)

Answer (score 0):

By default chrome/edge dev tools will show your app on the list when app is open on the screen that contains WebView (It will allow inspection of that WebView).

EDIT: WebView debug is enabled by default on simulators, on a real device you need to enable this explicitly (Thanks Robert( https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/#configure_webviews_for_debugging

Personally, I'm using stetho library which allows inspecting apps using chrome dev tools, It has really nice options. http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: Debugging of WebViews is disabled by default unless the Android app explicitly enables it: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging/webviews/#configure_webviews_for_debugging

Comment: Yeah, on real devices you need to WebView enabled debug. 
It works out of the hood with emulators. Thanks Robert