# How do I remotely debug Android Chrome browser tabs using IntelliJ?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, debugging, intellij-idea

Surely IntelliJ can connect to the Android Chrome browser on my Pixel 6a device and debug the website's source with breakpoints like my desktop Chrome.

Ideally, the answerer to this question creates the **Run/Debug Configuration** and check **Store as project file** in the IDE, opens the `.run/configuration.run.xml` file then share it here, if you believe you have a working configuration. Here's an example:

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="Server" type="ChromiumRemoteDebugType" factoryName="Chromium Remote" port="9229" restartOnDisconnect="true">
    <method v="2" />
  </configuration>
</component>
```

Support my device's IP address is 10.1.1.10, since I enabled Wi-Fi debugging, and the ADB server is running on port 5555.

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/remote-debugging Also be aware that if you using Chrome Remote Debugging, [Android Studio's `adb` may interfere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72536196/295004)

Comment: While ADB will let you debug your own app, Chrome tabs are actually opened by the Chrome process itself which won't be debugable.