How to remote debugging with chrome and pixel 9
When I go to chrome://inspect and stop/start USB debugging on my phone eventually I see "Pixel 9" appear but that's it. I don't get any options appear. According to chrome docs I should see an input with an "open" button.
Instead, after a number of seconds, "Pixel 9" just disappears. I then have to keep toggling the USB debugging until it appears again.
Is this a Pixel 9/chrome bug or...?

Windows 11
Chrome 128
Pixel 9, android 14


Just making sure that this isn't a possible Android Studio conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72536196/295004

Cheers Morrison. Hadn't even thought about adb, haven't ran android studio for a long time. I renamed adb (instead of deleting) and now the option stays.
